# First Black Hole Picture Takeaways

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, astronomy, event-horizon

We just have obtained the first "picture" of a black hole, the supermassive blackhole at the center of galaxy M87. As spelled in [this approved answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/471168/picture-of-sgr-a), there were multiple unsolved questions to be answered. Based on this picture, can we already confirm any of these? If not, what we will need?

I repeat the questions from the linked answer for simplicity:

> These observations would answer some practical questions about the black holes that have long intrigued us, questions like:
>
> 1) it will be that the black hole has the correct size as predicted by the Theory of General Relativity.
>
> 2) it will be that the event horizon (the boundary of the black hole) is circular (as predicted) or, in
>   contrast, is oblong (stretched).
>
> 3) it will be that the radio broadcasts extend more than you think.
>
> 4) it will be that there is some other deviation from the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the black hole is the right size. Or at least the size of the photon shadow yields a mass that agrees with the mass inferred by stellar dynamics in M87.

Yes, the shadow is very circular (to better than 10%), as predicted by GR.

Reference: [Akiyama et al. and the Event Horizon Telescope collaboration (2019)](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2041-8213/ab0ec7#apjlab0ec7s5).